# How to measure network latency between microservices?

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

We are developing microservices using full Jersey 2.x stack and deploying to the Cloud (OpenStack). We are also monitoring our endpoints (especially processing times) and we do see some serious differences between times reported by the Client and the Server.

For example:
We have a service A, and Client-A. service A reports avg response time to be 50 ms, but the Client-A has statistics that show that the avg response time from service A is 90 ms.

I think it is because of the network issues but it is very difficult to prove. I was thinking about implementing ClientRequestFilter, ClientResponseFilter, ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter and just exchange my own header with "current time millis" and verify this numbers on both client / container sides.

Is this a good approach to the problem?